# PHP script MYSQL database to migration in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-5.1

I have MYSQL database.
How can i convert database to migration on laravel 5.1
Any body have script?

Comment: I want to database to migrate .not migrate to database

Comment: I think everyone understand this perfectly fine it is still not a very good question. "I have a frog - I like it to be a fox how do I do?"

Comment: maybe this is not good question but  I need this script.

Comment: "I need this script" I rest my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate migration files based on existing database structure you can use one of available Laravel packages. I've used **Xethron/migrations-generator** in one of my projects - you can find it here: https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator.

There are some small issues running it with **Laravel 5.1**, but they are easy to solve - you can check the discussion here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-migrations-from-existing-database?page=1 - one entry needs to be added to your **composer.json**.

Once you have the package properly installed and configured, make sure you have correct database credentials in your **database.php** config file and then run **php artisan migrate:generate** and migration files will be generated.